# Is it possible to extend class with ParamSpec in Generic in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I have class, with `__call__`, so I want to specify its arguments in Generic. Also it should return AsyncIterator, so I wrote something like this:

```
IN = ParamSpec('IN')
OUT = TypeVar('OUT')


class Base(Generic[IN, OUT], metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    async def __call__(self,
                       *args: IN.args,
                       **kwargs: IN.kwargs
                       ) -> AsyncIterator[OUT]:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Foo(Base[IN, OUT]):
    def __init__(self, yield_value: OUT):
        self.yield_value = yield_value

    async def __call__(self,
                       *args: IN.args,
                       **kwargs: IN.kwargs
                       ) -> AsyncIterator[OUT]:
        while True:
            yield self.yield_value
```

And when I ran mypy it gave me 2 errors:

```
error: ParamSpec "IN" is unbound
error: Return type "AsyncIterator[OUT]" of "__call__" incompatible with return type "Coroutine[Any, Any, AsyncIterator[OUT]]" in supertype "Base"
```

So what exactly the first error does mean?
Also why it says that return type incompatible if annotations exactly the same?

UPD.

The second error can be fixed by removing async from the `Base.__call__`, not sure is it by design or not.

Comment: i don't know how ParamSpec works, but as it is, `IN` doesn't do anything `Foo`. It may be complaining about that, specifically mypy has no way to infer `IN` and therefore `IN.args` and `IN.kwargs`. I also suspect the second error is caused by the first

Comment: @joel beside the error it works perfectly, detects calls with wrong argument types (`Foo[[int], int](1)('1')`) and detects wrong object types (for example if you try to pass `Foo[[int], int]` as `Base[[str], int]`)

Comment: sure, but I meant within the above code - naturally, if you specify `IN` it will know what it should be. Could you add the line numbers of those mypy errors?

Comment: (well - tbh i missed that you could explicitly specify `IN`)